# multiple django apps with nginx proxy_pass and rewrite

Tags: django, url-rewriting, nginx, django-admin

I have a single django-admin app named `myapp` that I would like to deploy multiple instances of on different physical boxes, one per customer.  However, I'd like them all to be accessed from a similar domain, `mydomain.com/customer1/myapp`.

I've fiddled with specific proxy settings and tried multiple things suggested on SO, but none quite fit my use case... and since I know very little about both `nginx` and `django` I am at a loss!

My current nginx.conf is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com

    location ^~ /static {
        alias /path/to/static/files/;
    }
#    location / {
#        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
#    }
    location ^~ /customer1/myapp/static {
        alias /path/to/static/files/;
    }
    location /customer1/myapp {
        rewrite ^/customer1/myapp/(/?)(.*) /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

I can get to the login screen as expected via `myserver.com/customer1/myapp/admin`.  However when I attempt to log in, nginx rewrites my url to `myserver.com/admin` which isn't a valid url.  How do I keep nginx from actually rewriting the url and only change the url that is passed on to `127.0.0.1:8001`?

FWIW, I am using gunicorn to serve with `gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8001 -n myapp`.  If I uncomment the `/` location and remove the last two location blocks, the app works great.

I am far from set on this approach if there are alternatives. The goal is to avoid modifying django code for each deployment and instead just add minimal code to the nginx.conf for new deployments.

Comment: Questions about deployment may be more suitable for serverfault.com

Comment: I don't understand, are you just trying to make django url reverse to generate /customerX/myapp/admin/ instead of /admin/ ?

Comment: @jpic No, I want django to only see root urls.  e.g. `127.0.0.1:8001/admin`.  I assume I can do this with nginx, but I'm not sure how.  And noted about `serverfault.com`, I will post there if  I don't figure anything out here, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

basically, you specify url as part of the proxy_pass directive, the following location directive should do it:

```
location ~ ^/customer1/myapp(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/$2;
}
```

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass for the detailed explanation on how nginx passes the uri

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't realize I could use the groups in the following expression.  However, this re-writes my url in the browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/$2` I would prefer it to stay as is.  It also doesn't play nice with the django-admin login screen.

Comment: This works well for most of the app and I accepted, but the best solution I found was to use subdomains `customer.myserver.com` rather than including the customer in the main part of the url.

Comment: This answer is a BAD PRACTICE; please see http://serverfault.com/a/728792/110020 for the explanation of the issues.

Comment: I used your configuration to proxy_pass https://my_domain/router/ location to http://192.168.0.1:8000, that works but then the browser url got rewritten with http://192.168.0.1:8000/webman/index.cgi which is login page and then rest operations works with same IP based URL. I want to access my router console  https://my_domain/router/webman/index.cgi instead of changing URL to my internal IP address of the router... Can you please direct me how should I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following:

```
location /customer1/myapp {
    return 302 $uri/;
}
location /customer1/myapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/
}
```

Note that this is superior to using variables within `proxy_pass`, because if you do use variables, then [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) can no longer be of the default value `default`, and will be `off` instead, and then internal `302` redirects within your app will not be mapped to `/customer1/myapp/` after being fetched by nginx, which will likely cause you troubles and more 404s.

And, yes, using individual domains for individual customers is a better idea, because it's more secure (as far as cookie handling is concerned, for example).