# How to proxy_pass a route with parameters

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, axios

I am using a route with parameters on the front end to node express using axios:

```
await axios.delete(`/api/delete/file/${folder}`)
```

Then on node express I use the route with a parameter

server.js

```
import { deleteFile } from './node/controllers/delete-controller.js'
app.use('/api', router)
router.delete('/delete/file/:folder', deleteFile)
```

delete-controller.js

```
export const deleteFile = async (req, res) => {
  await unlink(`./projects/${req.params.folder}/data.json`)
  res.end()
}
```

On production, how should I set the nginx proxy pass? Currently I have this but it does not work.

```
location /api/delete/file {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5006/api/delete/file;
}
```

Or

```
location ~ ^/api/delete/file(/?)(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5006/api/delete/file$1;
}
```

I get: `404`

If I do

```
location /api/delete/file/?(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5006/api/delete/file;
}
```

I get: `405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367917/7865759), you need to `rewrite` url and remove `api` from `url` then route to the server

Comment: Why do I have to remove the `api`? I use it on other simple routes and works fine

Comment: You edit post and add `app.use('/api', router)`. before that I said that, cause I think your route has not `api` prefix.

Comment: Yeah that's right